# Google App Engine Python Cron Job

Tags: python, google-app-engine, cron

I wanted to run my cron job as 'schedule: every saturday every 2 minutes from 01:00 to 3:00', and it won't allow this format. Is it possible to set a cron job to target another cron job? Or is my schedule possible just not in the correct format?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you cannot combine the weekday option with the interval.

You could add a switch in the request handler of your cron-job, that will just exit if current week-day is not Saturday, while your cron.job is scheduled "every 2 minutes from 01:00 to 03:00". But that means that your handler will be called 300 times per week for doing nothing, and only doing something the other 60 times.

Alternatively, you could combine an "every saturday 01:00" cron-job (as dispatcher) that will create 60 push tasks (as worker) with countdown or ETA, spread between 01:00 and 03:00. However, I don't think the execution time is not guaranteed.